# Fixed Point and Proof theory

Tags: logic, proof, logic-programming, first-order-logic

For any given logic program, proof theory of it uses SLD (Selective Linear Definite) resolution to find the satisfiablity of the query. For the same logic program, we can apply fixed point theorem to find the models.

My question is,

should we consider finding fixed point of logic programs as proof theory or model theory or is it neither?

Comment: Is this a question for this area or somewhere else?  You might get a better answer on one of the other overflow boards for a theoretical question like this.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan http://cs.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: It's not a completely theoretical part of computer science.

Comment: Dunno.  This has been here for nearly an hour with no real help.  I can barely understand the question, but I'm not the most educated guy when it comes to stuff like this.  Just trying to get you more eys on your problem.

Comment: Model theory and Proof theory are different ways to give meaning to the given logic program.  I happen to solve use Fixed point semantics. I don't know where fixed point semantics fit in. https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~mjs/teaching/KnowledgeRep491/Stratified_491-2x1.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be *model theory* since the fixpoint semantics of a logic program is its model. However, we know that `|=` coincides with `|-` for logic programs, so the semantics based on proving (=resolution) coincide with the semantics based on the fixed points (models).

The preceding discussion is valid only for pure logic programs, i.e., no negation, bultins, arithmetics...